# Modeling Multiple User Roles in UML

Tags: uml

As a class assignment i am to to design an object-oriented web application online auction system. My question is how would i model a single user with different roles of bidder and seller in the Use Case and Class Diagrams respectively? 
For the UCD, does the user have to be represented as different actors and would there be the need for two separate 'User' classes in the Class Diagram?

Answer (score 0):

The users are represented by `Actor`s (represented as stick men on UC diagrams). Here the actor is not a single person but a certain role. Like on stage you can exchange the person, but the role stays the same. A single person may act at the same time as bidder and seller. But you have two roles, namely `Bidder` and `Seller` both being actors.